# Getting Outlook Calendar Items to Grid view in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, outlook

I am trying to get outlook calendar items using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook to a gridview table in ASP.NET. I have no problem getting the data to a listbox but I need to have it in a gridview table format.

I'm not getting any errors when running the code, it's just not showing any data.

```
        public void GetAllCalendarItems()
    {
        DataTable calendardata = new DataTable();
        calendardata.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
        calendardata.Columns.Add("StartDate", typeof(DateTime));

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNamespace = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder CalendarFolder = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items outlookCalendarItems = null;

        oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        mapiNamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        Recipient outlookAccount = oApp.Session.CreateRecipient("outofoffice");
        CalendarFolder = mapiNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(outlookAccount, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
        outlookCalendarItems = CalendarFolder.Items;
        outlookCalendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;

        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem item in outlookCalendarItems)
        {

                DataRow row = calendardata.NewRow();
                row["Subject"] = item.Subject;
                row["StartDate"] = item.Start.Date;

                foreach (DataRow dr in calendardata.Rows)
                {
                    tblCalendar.DataSource = calendardata;
                    tblCalendar.DataBind();
                }
        }
    }
```

Here is the asp.net code:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="tblCalendar" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" Visible="true">
        <RowStyle CssClass="myrow" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="myrow" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Subject" HeaderText="Subject" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDate" HeaderText="Start Date" />

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: It is possible the Calendar is not getting repainted.  Try setting DataSource to null : tblCalendar.DataSource = null;tblCalendar.DataSource = dt;

Comment: That still did not work.

Comment: Dos the DataTable dt contain data?  Put break point after data is put into table.  Then hover over dt variable, click on down arrow and then select Data Table Visualizer.

Comment: No, it is not. There is data in row["Subject"] = item.Subject; - but not in DataRow dr. I'm not sure how to get the data there.

Comment: You already put the rows into the datatable using DataRow row = calendardata.NewRow();  So you only need one foreach loop.  Then after the foreach you just need one statement : tblCalendar.DataSource = calendardata;

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still missing something. You say I only need one foreach loop? I have edited my question to show you the changes I have tried but the table is still not being created and the foreach at the end has no data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved my issue:

```
dt.Rows.Add(new Object[] { item.Subject, item.Start.Date }); 
tblCalendar.DataBind();`
```

Comment: I don't think the first line does anything.  There is no table dt in your code unless you meant table tblCalendar.

Answer (score 0):

Code should look like this :

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem item in outlookCalendarItems)
{
    DataRow row = calendardata.NewRow();
    row["Subject"] = item.Subject;
    row["StartDate"] = item.Start.Date;
}
tblCalendar.DataSource = calendardata;
```

Comment: I was able to get it working by using the following: dt.Rows.Add(new Object[] { item.Subject, item.Start.Date }); and then - tblCalendar.DataBind(); Thank you for your suggestions.